# What to use instead of Buffer(bitmap)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using the following method to convert files into base64 encoding and it's been working fine for a long time, but I see now that Buffer is depricated.

```
        // function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
        function base64_encode(file) {
        
            var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
            // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
            return new Buffer(bitmap).toString("base64");
        }
        let base64String = base64_encode("Document.png");
```

Can someone please help me modify this to work with the new suggested method as I'm not sure how to modify it myself?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `Buffer` that is deprecated but its [constructor](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0005), so instead of `new Buffer()` you use e.g. `Buffer.from`.

However [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) already returns a `Buffer` if no `encoding` is specified, so there is not really a need to pass that to another buffer. Instead you can do `return fs.readFileSync(file).toString("base64")`

Using the `Sync` part of the API is most of the time something would like to avoid and if possible switch over to the promise-based API.